# i am making a level lock unlock system using unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, monodevelop

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class loadlevels : MonoBehaviour {
public Button b2;
public Button b3;
void OnLevelWasLoaded()
{

    int MyLevel = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Level"); 

    switch (MyLevel) {

    case 2: b2.interactable = true; 
        b2.image.sprite = Resources.Load<Sprite> ("UISprite");

        break;

    case 3: b3.interactable = true; 
        b3.image.sprite = Resources.Load<Sprite>("UISprite");
        break;



    }
}
}
```

I used playerprefs to save the button state but i encounter a problem that when unlocking the third level which is button 3, button 2 goes to its locked state. it is weird that button 2 is not saving when unlocking the third level.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want array of buttons that will be enabled up to certain index. You code with `switch` is enabling only one button that exactly matches the level.

```
public Button[] buttons = new Button[4]; 
// don't forget to create / set in array

for( int level = 0; level <= myLevel; level++)
{
   buttons[level].interactable = true; 
   buttons[level].image.sprite = Resources.Load<Sprite> ("UISprite");
 }
```

Comment: this will unlock all the levels at once!?

Comment: you need to add `int myLevel = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Level"); `

Comment: what i did was making a GetInt for each level and that fixed my issue!